# Local SQL database interface to cloud database

Tags: sql, cloud

Excuse me if the question is simple. We have multiple medical clinics running each running their own SQL database EHR.

Is there anyway I can interface each local SQL database with a cloud system?

I essentially want to use the current patient data that one is consulting with at that moment to generate a pathology request that links to a cloud ?google app engine database.

Answer (score 0):

As a medical student / software developer this project of yours interests me greatly!

If you don't mind me asking, where are you based? I'm from the UK and unfortunately there's just no way a system like this would get off the ground as most data is locked in proprietary databases.

What you're talking about is fairly complex anyway, whatever country you're in I assume there would have to be a *lot* of checks / security around any cloud system that dealt with patient data. Theoretically though, what you would want to do ideally is create an online database (cloud, hosted, intranet etc), and scrap the local databases entirely.

You then have one 'pool' of data each clinic can pull information from (i.e. ALL records for patient #3563). They could then edit that data and/or insert new records and SAVE them, exporting them back to the main database.

If there is a need to keep certain information private to one clinic only this could still be achieved on one database in a number of ways, or you could retain parts of the local database and have them merge with the cloud data as they're requested by the clinic

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit outdated, but you guys should checkout https://www.firebase.com/. It would let you do what you want fairly easily. We just did this for a client in the exact same business your are.

Basically, Firebase lets you work with a Central Database on the Cloud, that is automatically synchronised with all its front-ends. It even handles losing the connection to the server automagically. It's the best solution I've found so far to keep several systems running against one only cloud database.

We used to have our own backend that would try its best to sync changes, but you need to be really careful with inter-system unique IDs for your tables (i.e. going to one of the branches  and making a new user won't yield the same id that one that already exists in any other branch or the central database). It becomes cumbersome very quickly.

CakePHP can automatically generate this kind of Unique IDs pretty easily and automatically, but you still have to work on sync'ing all the local databases with the central repository.